# Lua collision nil value

Tags: lua, physics, collision, null

When I tried to execute the following piece of code it gives me this error:

> Attempt to index field 'other' (a nil value)

but I don't know why.

The code:

```
function onCollision(event)
 if event.phase == "began" then 
    if event.other.star == "star" then
       score = score + 1
    elseif event.other.mine1 == "mine1" then
       if jet.collided == false then
         timer.cancel(tmr)    
         jet.collided = true    
         jet.bodyType = "static"
         explode()
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It means that `event.other` is nil.

Comment: What lhf said. Which means that the value passed in to `onCollision` is a table (or quacks like one), but that it has no field named `other`. Perhaps the field is actually named `Other`. Perhaps `onCollision` has not been passed the object you think it has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @lhf and @RBerteig said the problem is `event.other` is `nil`, so trying to access the `star` member fails attempting to index a nil value.

Assuming `event.other` can indeed be `nil`, the idiomatic way to solve your problem would be to add a nil check to the previous if `if event.phase == "began" and event.other then`, since both if and else conditions depend on `event.other` to be set.

```
function onCollision(event)
 if event.phase == "began" and event.other then 
    if event.other.star == "star" then
       score = score + 1
    elseif event.other.mine1 == "mine1" then
       if jet.collided == false then
         timer.cancel(tmr)    
         jet.collided = true    
         jet.bodyType = "static"
         explode()
       end
    end
  end
 end
```

In case you're wondering about the message of 'attempt to index field' you can also read more about [lua index metamethod here](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html)